# Change in header.twig file doesn't appear opencart 3.x

Tags: templates, opencart, opencart-3

I made these changes in header.twig file but it doesn't appear in front end

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div id="logo">{% if logo %}<a href="{{ home }}"><img src="{{ logo }}" title="{{ name }}" alt="{{ name }}" class="img-responsive" /></a>{% else %}
          <h1><a href="{{ home }}">{{ name }}</a></h1>
          {% endif %}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7">         
         {{ menu }}
        </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">{{ search }}</div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">{{ cart }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: because this app is such garbage code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for "header.twig" modification file in system/storage/modification.
If you have modification there, you should edit the modification file.

It is common problem :D

Comment: Hi Ivan thanx there was only one file which doesn't have the content, however, I deleted the cache from system/storage/cache and was able to see the changes :-)  So u Can Modify the answer if possible

Comment: this answer is wrong, you should never edit the modification file directly because it will simply be overwritten anytime you refresh the cache.

Answer (score 1):

What everyone else mentioned here is incorrect. Don't modify those files. You simply need to go into your admin dashboard. Go to Dashboard.

In the upper-right hand corner, right below your Logout link, you'll see a settings icon/button. When you hover over it, the tooltip should say "Developer Settings." Click that and you'll see options to turn your cache off. Turn it off for both Theme and SAAS, but also click refresh next to both. Now, you just refreshed your caches and any changes you make will show up immediately.

Just make sure to turn those options back on once you are done developing.

Comment: nope didnt work, what did work was uninstall this garbage code from our server lol

Answer (score 0):

One reason maybe you have not refreshed modification, Extension -> Modification -> refresh.

Another reason, you have to enable debugging in Environment.php file,

system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php
Find

$this->debug = (bool) $options['debug'];
Replace:

$this->debug = (bool) true;